# How to position a div in the flow under a fixed div containing a scalable image

Tags: html, css

So I have a fixed div with title and image below the title, and I want to then have another div, in the flow immediately under the fixed div. The fixed div with title and image will change size as the browser width changes, up to a maximum width of 700px. As the fixed div with image changes size the div containing text under the fixed div should maintain a a relative position below the bottom of the image.

I've tried implementing a wrapper around the fixed div, and also tried margin-top for the div containing the text but no matter what I try the text flows under the fixed div.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated! This is what I currently have:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 700px;
}

.title-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.title {
width:100%;
max-width: 700px;
}

.image {
width: 100%;
}

.image img {
width:100%;
}

.text {
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-wrapper">

                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Planes</h2>

                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/47044/aircraft-landing-reach-injection-47044.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Plane1">
                        <!-- <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/40753/military-raptor-jet-f-22-airplane-40753.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Plane2">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/164646/pexels-photo-164646.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Plane3"> -->
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="text">
                <div>
                    <h3>TEXT 1</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium veniam consequuntur libero? Explicabo consectetur rerum odit? Qui ea dolore culpa. Provident, exercitationem reiciendis voluptatum nulla quo nihil iste? Non doloremque officia ex dicta, ea molestias corporis. Quisquam, tenetur! Consequatur totam quaerat ullam incidunt quas nostrum expedita, quidem iste tempora est blanditiis corrupti sunt id! Esse necessitatibus non harum, ad quisquam unde, eius placeat est explicabo ex repudiandae suscipit, ipsum tempora a quibusdam facere porro officia magnam dolorum fuga iste. Quam, consequatur provident reiciendis quis doloribus at hic itaque soluta maiores libero voluptas assumenda, ut alias mollitia corrupti nulla fuga autem sapiente recusandae, aspernatur ad sed quasi earum. Nostrum, alias veritatis est qui quae ratione. Dignissimos et eum modi, beatae odio porro totam, minus debitis eius expedita mollitia ea est veritatis, ut possimus delectus! Nesciunt, ad quos quasi soluta error cum veritatis aliquam, temporibus optio, commodi fuga perferendis aperiam dignissimos debitis?</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index to control the stacking context. You can also use planes image as background on .text div.

CSS for z-index below:

```
.title-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My understanding of z-index is that it allows divs to be placed on different layers. Sorry if I caused confusion with terminology, but I'm actually trying to get the second div immediately below a fixed div that contains an image that will scale with browser width. All divs will be on the same top layer.